# Formatting datetime objects stored in a defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, formatting

Say you have a regular dict with each key representing a single time object you can format it and print it to the screen like so:

```
d = { key : DT_object}

#Print formatted key with corresponding formatted datetime object.
for key, value in d.iteritems():          
  print '%s %s' % (key,value)
```

Now if we complicate things a little more and store a list of datetime objects for each key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = { key : [DT_object,DT_object]}
for key, value in d.iteritems():          
  print '%s %s' % (key,value)
```

Our formatting process now breaks down. What would be the proper code to let python cycle through each object in the list and format it?

Comment: What do you want it to print? Mine prints the list of values: [DT_object,DT_object]

Comment: you need to clearly state how your current output is wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `join` and make all objects strings in the list of values

```
 '%s %s' % (key," ".join([str(x) for x in value]))
```

Using `str.format` with an example:

```
d = { "foo" : [datetime.now(),datetime.now()]}
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print '{} {}'.format(key, " ".join([str(x) for x in value]))

foo 2014-08-13 20:34:11.940936 2014-08-13 20:34:11.940981
```

You can also use one of the `datetime` methods to change to a string:

```
print '{} {}'.format(key, " ".join([x.isoformat() for x in value]))
foo 2014-08-13T20:36:08.900873 2014-08-13T20:36:08.900910
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
d = { key : [DT_object,DT_object]}
for key, value in d.iteritems():          
  print '%s %s' % (key,list(map(str,value)))
```

may be what you want ...